# Correct way to close capybara (with poltergeist/phantomjs)

Tags: ruby, tcp, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm runnning a lot of jobs through capybara on my linux server. I'm using the poltergeist phantomjs driver. After A while I'm getting a lot of these errors:

```
Errno::EMFILE Too many open files - socket(2)
```

I looked in `lsof` and it looks like I have a LOT of these:

```
ruby      32316   deployer  320u     IPv4  9893211        0t0      TCP localhost:55062 (LISTEN)
```

Now i'm suspecting that it might be because I'm not getting the connection correctly closed?

What would be the correct way of terminating after running something like the following:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:js_errors => false})
end

Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.run_server = false

@session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
@session.visit('some_url')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run `@session.driver.quit`.

Comment: But are you sure that will terminate the TCP connection?

Comment: I am not sure, but it ought to. I encourage you to try.

Comment: Well it helped, I think, on the TCP connections but I still get the error, however now I see a lot of these in `lsof`: `ruby      19441   deployer  137w      REG      9,3 1895691531 57021609 /home/deployer/apps/autouncle/shared/log/sidekiq.log
ruby      19441   deployer  138r     FIFO      0,8        0t0 11683098 pipe
ruby      19441   deployer  139w     FIFO      0,8        0t0 11683098 pipe`

Comment: Right, that looks like a bug. I've filed an issue to keep track of it: https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/310

Comment: It doesn't have #quit method.